# How to list duplicate records?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure:

```
id|date|studenttypeid|name|audituser
1|.....|4|Jason|....
2|.....|4|Robin|....
3|.....|4|Jason|....
4|.....|4|Dan|....
5|.....|4|Robin|....
```

I need to list all records which are duplicates on `studenttypeid + name`.

With the above data, the query should give me the following output:

```
1|.....|4|Jason|....
2|.....|4|Robin|....
3|.....|4|Jason|....
5|.....|4|Robin|....
```

How can I achieve this on SQL Server 2008?

Comment: why is `5|.....|4|Robin|....` still included on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a group by and then join back to the original table, like this:

```
WITH Temp(StudentTypeId, Name) AS(
    SELECT 
        StudentTypeId, Name
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY 
        StudentTypeId, Name
    HAVING Count(1) > 1
)

SELECT YourTable.*
FROM YourTable
INNER JOIN Temp
    ON YourTable.StudentTypeId = Temp.StudentTypeId
    AND YourTable.Name = Temp.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT ID, DATE, studenttypeid, name, audituser
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, DATE, studenttypeid, name, audituser,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studenttypeid, name
                              ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM   yourTableName
) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c17f/3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include every occurrence of the duplicates, some more methods using CROSS APPLY...

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) * FROM people p2 WHERE p2.ID <> p.ID AND p2.name = p.name AND p.studenttypeid = p2.studenttypeid
) as pWithDups
```

Or an EXISTS check

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM people p2 
    WHERE p2.ID <> p.ID AND p2.name = p.name AND p.studenttypeid = p2.studenttypeid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   yourtable a
JOIN   (SELECT studenttypeid,
               name
        FROM   yourtable
        GROUP  BY studenttypeid,
                  name
        HAVING Count(studenttypeid) > 1) b ON b.name = a.name
ORDER  BY a.id
```